# Does Hessian of rank one mean curvature in one direction and flatness in the other

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I'm following a course on convex optimization by Stephen P. Boyd. https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE-YCVX0001+1T2020/

My question is about Lecture 3 (https://youtu.be/JrWSn5wW_Z0). Boyd gives a function:

**quadratic-over-linear**: $f(x,y) = x^2/y,\: y>0$

[image]

The Hessian matrix of the function is:
$$\nabla^2f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}2/y&&-2x/y^2\\-2x/y^2&&2x^2/y^3\end{bmatrix}=\frac{2}{y^3}\begin{bmatrix}y\\-x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\-x\end{bmatrix}^T$$

So  the Hessian matrix has rank one. Boyd says at https://youtu.be/JrWSn5wW_Z0?t=1527 :

> The fact that it's rank one tells you that at any point on that surface it's
> sort of curving in one direction, but not the other.
> Alright, so that's what it says. In one direction, it's flat.
> In the other direction, it's got positive curvature.

I don't see why it's true for **any** point. For example, $\nabla^2f(1,1)= \begin{bmatrix}2&&-2\\-2&&2\end{bmatrix}$ . So the function has curvature in both $x$ and $y$ direction.

Maybe Boyd meant to say that this is true for any point $(x_0, y_0)$ where $\nabla f(x_0,y_0) = 0$ ?
In that case the line $x_0=0$ would represent the set of such points, and the Hessian matrix would be $\nabla^2f(0,y_0)= \begin{bmatrix}2/y_0&&0\\0&&0\end{bmatrix}$. This would mean that the function has curvature only in $y$ direction.

So, what am I missing here? Is the claim really true for any point? Is it true only for points where the gradient is zero? Is it true for **any function** in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer.**

If you make a parabolic trough out of paper that  rests flat on a table on a single line of contact, and imagine walking in any direction that is not  that purely flat direction on the table, you will note that you curve upward.

**Long answer.**
It may be helpful to review how curvature is related to real-world experience.
We know from experience that as we travel on a curved path on a surface at constant speed  the force we experience due to acceleration has a component that pushes us up or down in relation to the surface normal. It reflects the fact that the surface is curved. To test for this curvature in a given tangent direction on the surface $f(x,y)-z=0$ imagine traveling on a parametrized path on the surface that passes through that given tangent direction. The Chain Rule tells you the tangent vector $\vec v =< \dot x, \dot y, \dot z>$ satisfies $ f_x \dot x+ f_y \dot y - \dot z=0$ from which we see that the normal vector direction is that of $N=< f_x,f_y, -1>$. Differentiating again we deduce
$Q=f_{xx} \dot x^2+  + 2f_{xy} \dot x \dot y+ f_{yy}\dot y^2 =-\vec A \cdot N$ where $\vec A$ is the acceleration.  Thus the Hessian quadratic form $Q= \vec v^t H \vec v$ can be interpreted as a way to measure curvature as we travel in any specified tangent direction $\vec v$.

**Diagonalization theory summarized**.
Symmetric quadratic forms can always be expressed (using eigenvector, eigenvalue theory) in purest form as  a linear combination of pure squares of certain orthogonal components of $\vec v$. So  in particular our curvature formula can be written as $Q= \kappa_1 (\vec v\cdot e_1)^2 + \kappa_2(\vec v\cdot e_2)^2 $ where $e_1, e_2$ are two mutually orthogonal unit length tangent vectors. These directions are called the principal curvature directions on the surface. In the case where $\kappa_2=0$ but $\kappa_1\ne 0$ we say the surface is flat in  that direction. It is actually flat in only that one direction. In any other direction it is  curved, because there is a component of $\vec v$ in the direction of $\vec e_1$ where the surface is curving.

Comment: Very interesting! I totally misunderstood the meaning of "direction". My lack of training in differential geometry showed. So, there are two principal curvature directions for the surface $x^2/y-z=0$ at the point $<a, b>$. The first one is $<a, b>$ with $\kappa_1=0$. I should've guessed it since the surface is just a cone laid on its side. Of course there should be no curvature in the direction from the apex to the base. The second one is $<b, -a>$ and has $\kappa_2=2\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^3}$. The acceleration analogy is very useful too!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!